# move one div over another

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have two **div** elements that are twins (i.e. their dimensions and contents are identical). I want to move of those div-s over another, so that their corners are at exactly the same coordinates. What I try to do is:

```
var offset = $('div#placeholder').offset();
$('div#overlay').css('position', 'absolute').css('left', offset.left + 'px').css('top', offset.top + 'px')
```

-- but this causes the overlay to be exactly (or almost exactly, taking subpixel accuracy into account) 16px below the placeholder (below, i.e. overlay_top = placeholder_top + 16px).

I'm aware that **offset()** gives position relative to the document, and **position: absolute** sets position relative to **body** element, but compensating for **body offset()** doesn't help much (I'm getting 8px offset, equal to margins):

```
offset.top -= $('body').offset().top;
offset.left -= $('body').offset().left;
```

Also, compensating for **body** margins (in case they were different that **offset()** didn't help, as they were set to 8px).

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:** Take a look at [here](http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/9239/zrzutekranu2b.png) - I'm getting the same result in FireFox 3.6.3 and Opera 10.10.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after but try adding some z-index:1;(2, 3 etc) properties to your CSS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspicious that you have some CSS rule being applied based on a class/name/element type in the stylesheet.  I suggest that you try setting margin/padding on the element to 0 via javascript.  You might also want to use WebDeveloper or FireBug and inspect the computed styles on the element after repositioning to see what styles are being applied and from where.

Comment: I created blank page and still managed to reproduce the problem. But when I switched to positioning child elements of div (i.e. inputs), everything started working perfectly. I still don't know why, but I don't have time to investigate this further.